# environment aligned does not align on the left side despite fleqn option

Tags: equations, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength{\mathindent}{14bp}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{14}
\left\{

    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{split}
            T(E_1 \Fcap  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \\
            T(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcup  T(E_2)  
        \end{split}\\
        \begin{split}
            H(E_1 \Fcap  E_2)&=\left[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \right] \Fcup  \left[-(E_1 \Fcap E_2)\right] \\
                             &=\left[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \right] \Fcup  \left[-(E_1) \Fcup T(-E_2)\right] \\
                             &=\left[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \right] \Fcup  T(-E_1) \Fcup  T(-E_2) 
        \end{split}\\
        \begin{split}
            H(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  \left[T(-E_1\Fcup E_2) \right]  \\
                              &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  \left[T(-E_1 \Fcap -E_2) \right]  \\
                              &= T(E_1)\Fcup T(E_2) \Fcup  \left[T(-E_1) \Fcap  T(-E_2) \right] 
        \end{split}
    \end{aligned}
  \right.

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

I would like to have the first two lines left-aligned. I unsuccessfully tried several solutions. Can somebody help me?
[image: displayed equation with first two lines aligned on the right]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your code is not compilable now, possibly missing packages.

Comment: Off topic: *never* leave a blank line within the scope of any math expression. It will result in errors being detected.

Comment: Why not combine the first `split` with the second `split`? Also your code is not compilable. What did you use for `Fcap` and `Fcup`?

Comment: How are \Fcap and \Fcup defined?

Comment: Thank you for your useful comments. I did not include the special definitions of Fcup and Fcap, namely: \newcommand*{\Fcap}{\ensuremath{{_\cap}}} and
\newcommand*{\Fcup}{\ensuremath{{^\cup}}} .

Answer (score 1):

1. No blank line inside `equation`
2. No `split`
3. Remove the redundant (and harmful) `\left` and `\right`.

I also added some vertical space to better distinguish the equation groups.

I provided dummy definitions for `\Fcup` and `\Fcap` just to make the code compilable.

```
\documentclass[twoside,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength{\mathindent}{14bp}
\newcommand{\Fcap}{\cap}
\newcommand{\Fcup}{\cup}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{14}
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    T(E_1 \Fcap  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \\[1ex]
    T(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcup  T(E_2) \\[1ex]
    H(E_1 \Fcap  E_2) &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  [-(E_1 \Fcap E_2)] \\
                      &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  [-(E_1) \Fcup T(-E_2)] \\
                      &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  T(-E_1) \Fcup  T(-E_2) \\[1ex]
    H(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1\Fcup E_2) ]  \\
                      &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1 \Fcap -E_2) ]  \\
                      &= T(E_1)\Fcup T(E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1) \Fcap  T(-E_2) ] 
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the comments, I guess that you want a better definition for `\Fcup` and `\Fcap`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength{\mathindent}{14bp}
\newcommand{\Fcap}{\mathbin{{}_\cap\kern-\scriptspace}}
\newcommand{\Fcup}{\mathbin{{}^\cup\kern-\scriptspace}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{14}
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    T(E_1 \Fcap  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) \\[1ex]
    T(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1) \Fcup  T(E_2) \\[1ex]
    H(E_1 \Fcap  E_2) &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  [-(E_1 \Fcap E_2)] \\
                      &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  [-(E_1) \Fcup T(-E_2)] \\
                      &=[ T(E_1) \Fcap  T(E_2) ] \Fcup  T(-E_1) \Fcup  T(-E_2) \\[1ex]
    H(E_1 \Fcup  E_2) &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1\Fcup E_2) ]  \\
                      &= T(E_1\Fcup E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1 \Fcap -E_2) ]  \\
                      &= T(E_1)\Fcup T(E_2) \Fcup  [T(-E_1) \Fcap  T(-E_2) ] 
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost gave a solution yet you did it. Ah!

Comment: I see that the solution was simpler than I thought it was. I forgot in my post to include the definition of Fcap and Fcup (namely: \newcommand*{\Fcap}{\ensuremath{{_\cap}}} and \newcommand*{\Fcup}{\ensuremath{{^\cup}}}) but your idea to define them as \cap and \cup respectively allowed me to copy and paste your code without changes. As a beginner, I learned a lot.

Comment: @lazerius I'm not sure what would be the meaning of those symbols; maybe you should prefer `\newcommand{\Fcap}{\mathbin{{}_{\cap}\kern-\scriptspace}}` and similarly for `\Fcup`. I see no reason for `\ensuremath`, as these symbols are math.